# Setting active object through python issues

Tags: python, scripting, modifiers, add-on

I am working on an addon that creates siding, it also allows you to cut out rectangles in it for windows and doors. It uses *Boolean* modifiers for this. When you select *bricks* it cuts the brick then it cuts the mortar then it joins the two, but currently I am having trouble getting it to cut the mortar properly.

Run the code from the *Text Editor*, go to *Add Mesh* > *JARCH Vis* > *Add Siding*, then once the object is added go to *Properties* > *Modifiers* > *JARCH Vis*, then change the *Material* to *bricks*, click *Cutouts* and enter something like `5, 2, 2, 2`.

You will notice how it does cut through the brick, but not through the mortar. The code for all this starts at line `1,524`. It is like

```
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = mortar
```

isn't switching right, but if you check `active object` it is correct. So I don't know why the modifier is being applied to *o* but not *mortar*. Here is the [python file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B35OsPAJ46kvNVhTOU5FUzh2aXM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I think it is related to context - try putting your panel into the 3dview - `bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"` and `bl_region_type = "UI"`. Not sure of a workaround to change the active object from a panel in the properties window.

Comment: @sambler that worked, I had to change my code a little, but it is getting the context right now. I don't mind just moving the whole panel out to `VIEW_3D` in some ways it is better, as the modifier panel is now less cluttered. Do you mind posting that back as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this issue when using a panel in the properties window to alter the active object. It would be related to the context.

The easy fix is to place your panel in the 3dview. This is just a matter of changing the panel's `bl_space_type` to `VIEW_3D` and `bl_region_type` to `UI`

It is possible that you can override the context to get it working, [this answer explains that](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6912/935) and links to more information.